# construct matrix by applying derivatives to another matrix

Tags: matrix

Say you have a vector like the following

```
NN[\[Xi]_, \[Eta]_] := ( {
   {1/4 (1 - \[Xi]) (1 - \[Eta])},
   {1/4 (1 + \[Xi]) (1 - \[Eta])},
   {1/4 (1 + \[Xi]) (1 + \[Eta])},
   {1/4 (1 - \[Xi]) (1 + \[Eta])}
  } )
```

and you would like to construct a matrix of 2 columns, where the first column is the result of applying the derivative to the vector with respect to `\[Xi]` and the second column with respect to `\[Eta]`. I tried this:

```
DNN[\[Xi]_, \[Eta]_] := ( {
   {\!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Xi]\)]\(NN[\[Xi], \
\[Eta]]\)\), \!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Xi]\)]\(NN[\[Xi], \[Eta]]\)\)}
  } )
```

But then I get extra brackets (see figure).

[image]

Is there an easier way to do this than the brute force approach where I construct the matrix as follows?

```
DNN[\[Xi]_, \[Eta]_] := ( {
   {\!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Xi]\)]\(\(NN[\[Xi], \
\[Eta]]\)[\([1]\)]\)\), \!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Eta]\)]\(\(NN[\[Xi], \[Eta]]\
\)[\([1]\)]\)\)},
   {\!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Xi]\)]\(\(NN[\[Xi], \
\[Eta]]\)[\([2]\)]\)\), \!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Eta]\)]\(\(NN[\[Xi], \[Eta]]\
\)[\([2]\)]\)\)},
   {\!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Xi]\)]\(\(NN[\[Xi], \
\[Eta]]\)[\([3]\)]\)\), \!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Eta]\)]\(\(NN[\[Xi], \[Eta]]\
\)[\([3]\)]\)\)},
   {\!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Xi]\)]\(\(NN[\[Xi], \
\[Eta]]\)[\([4]\)]\)\), \!\(
     \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Eta]\)]\(\(NN[\[Xi], \[Eta]]\
\)[\([4]\)]\)\)}
  } )
```

Comment: Is this what you want 
`DNN[\[Xi]_, \[Eta]_] := Transpose[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Xi]\)]\(NN[\[Xi], \[Eta]]\)\), \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(\[Eta]\)]\(NN[\[Xi], \[Eta]]\)\)}]`

Answer (score 2):

```
DNN[ξ_, η_] := D[Flatten@NN[ξ, η], {{ξ, η}}]
DNN[ξ, η] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

(The first column is w.r.t ξ and the second is w.r.t to η. In the question both are computed w.r.t to ξ, although the wording indicates that both partial derivatives are desired.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flatten to remove the extra parentheses:

```
Transpose[Flatten[DNN[ξ, η], 1]];
MatrixForm[%]
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up using `ArrayFlatten`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Transpose[Inner[D[#1, #2] &, Transpose[NN], {\[Xi]_, \[Eta]_}, List]]
```